# Is there a way to call two function-based views from views.py from one url? - Django or even by using Class-based view

Tags: python, html, django, highcharts

I have tried two different style of views: Function-based and class-based. I have two functions in my views.py and i don't know how to call both of them under single same url. I have seen suggestions to combine both functions into one but it still doesn't work.

Tried get() from class-based view and called the same url with different views

```
    path('home/dashboard/', views.get_profile, name='dashboard'),
    path('home/dashboard/', views.get_dept, name='dashboard'),

         def get_dept(request, *args, **kwargs):
            dataset = Department.objects.all() \
                   .values('department') \
                   .annotate(IT_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="IT")),
                           Sales_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="Sales")),
                           Admin_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="Admin")),
                           HR_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="HR"))) \
                   .order_by('department')

        categories = list()
        IT_series_data = list()
        Sales_series_data = list()
        Admin_series_data = list()
        HR_series_data = list()

        for entry in dataset:
            categories.append('%s Department' % entry['department'])
            IT_series_data.append(entry['IT_count'])
            Sales_series_data.append(entry['Sales_count'])
            Admin_series_data.append(entry['Admin_count'])
            HR_series_data.append(entry['HR_count'])

        IT_series = {
            'name': 'IT',
            'data': IT_series_data,
            'color': 'green'
        }

        Sales_series = {
            'name': 'Sales',
            'data': Sales_series_data,
            'color': 'yellow'
        }

        Admin_series = {
            'name': 'Admin',
            'data': Admin_series_data,
            'color': 'red'
        }

        HR_series = {
            'name': 'HR',
            'data': HR_series_data,
            'color': 'blue'
        }

        chart2 = {
            'chart': {
                'type': 'column',
                'backgroundColor': '#E3F0E6',
                'option3d': {
                    'enabled': "true",
                    'alpha': 10,
                    'beta': 15,
                    'depth': 50,
                }
            },
            'title': {'text': 'Containers per department'},
            'xAxis': {'categories': categories},
            'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'No.of containers'},
                'tickInterval': 1
                    },
            'plotOptions': {
                'column': {
                    'pointPadding': 0.2,
                    'borderWidth': 0,
                    'depth': 60,
                }
            },
            'series': [IT_series, Sales_series, Admin_series, HR_series],
            'colorByPoint': "true",
        }

        dump2 = json.dumps(chart2)

        return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'chart2': dump2})


def get_profile(request, *args, **kwargs):
        dataset = Profile.objects \
            .values('is_active') \
            .annotate(is_active_count=Count('is_active', filter=Q(is_active=True)),
                      not_is_active_count=Count('is_active', filter=Q(is_active=False))) \

        # categories = list('User')
        is_active_series_data = list()
        not_is_active_series_data = list()

        for entry in dataset:
            # categories.append('User')
            is_active_series_data.append(entry['is_active_count'])
            not_is_active_series_data.append(entry['not_is_active_count'])

        is_active_series = {
            'name': 'Active user',
            'data': is_active_series_data,
            'color': '#23CE3F'
        }

        not_is_active_series = {
            'name': 'Inactive user',
            'data': not_is_active_series_data,
            'color': '#FB3A3A'
        }

        chart = {
            'chart': {
                'type': 'column',
                'backgroundColor': '#E3F0E6',
                'options3d': {
                    'enabled': "true",
                    'alpha': 10,
                    'beta': 15,
                    'depth': 50,
                }
            },
            'title': {'text': 'Active user on Current Platform'},
            'xAxis': {'categories': ['Active', 'Inactive']},
            'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'No.of users'},
                'tickInterval': 1
                    },
            'plotOptions': {
                'column': {
                    'pointPadding': 0.2,
                    'borderWidth': 0,
                    'depth': 60,
                }
            },
            'series': [is_active_series, not_is_active_series]
        }

        dump = json.dumps(chart)

        return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'chart': dump})
```

Comment: You mean you want a user to go to one GET URL and then Django to present two views?  I don't think that's possible.  Django usually has a 1:1 mapping between the URL and the "do stuff" function. You can separate URLS  for GET and POST so you have one route and one view for GET and one route and one view for POST (with the same route path) but if you want to display chart and chart2 in dashboard then you will need to pass the two charts in the conext as separate variables and then your dashboard view will show them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way in django to put two views against one url. Maybe you can combine those functions in one Class based view and its pretty simple actually. For example:

```
# view
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class DashboardView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'accounts/dashboard.html'

     def get_dept(self):
        # rest of the code....
        dump2 = json.dumps(chart2)
        return dump2

    def get_profile(self):
        # rest of the code....
        dump = json.dumps(chart)
        return dump

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChartView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['chart'] = self.get_profile()
        context['chart2'] = self.get_dept()
        return context

# url
path('home/dashboard/', views.DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

And in template, you should get the values in `{{ chart }}` and `{{ chart2 }}` variables.

Comment: What is ChartView?

Answer (score 1):

No. A Django view is essentially a function that processes your `request` (an `HttpRequest` object) and returns an `HttpResponse` object containing your HTML page or JSON document or whatever response is expected. So there can only be one view function processing your request.

Note that a class-based view in the end is also just a function (the `.as_view()` returns the classes `dispatch` method as a function).

Of course, from within one function view, you can call other python functions to return whatever results are needed to produce the desired result. In your case, you just want to produce two charts to pass to the same template (*dashboard.html*).

So instead of making them return `render(request, template, context), just make them return the data for context. Then your one view can combine both contexts into one:

```
def dashboard_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    dump1 = get_dept()  # note you don't use request, *args, **kwargs so you don't need to add them as params to get_dept()
    dump2 = get_profile()  # idem
    context = {'chart1': dump1, 'chart2': dump2}
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

The answer of @ruddra is a similar approach using a class-based view. That would be the preferred "Django" way.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to achieve is getting data from both functions in one view, you should pass the info to the context from one view.

example:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get_profile()
        dataset = Profile.objects \
            .values('is_active') \
            .annotate(is_active_count=Count('is_active', filter=Q(is_active=True)),
                      not_is_active_count=Count('is_active', 
        filter=Q(is_active=False)))
        return dataset


    def get_dept(request, *args, **kwargs):
        dataset = Department.objects.all() \
                   .values('department') \
                   .annotate(IT_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="IT")),
                           Sales_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="Sales")),
                           Admin_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="Admin")),
                           HR_count=Count('department', 
                           filter=Q(department="HR"))) \
                   .order_by('department')

       return dataset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = self.get_profile()
        context['other_data'] = self.get_depth()
```

Then you can just call the class based view and the context will be availabe

Answer (score 0):

how i render the data into template

### i want to update the logo into base.html  from the any template files

on django we extending the base.html or any html file

we are create one block into that block part will be added into that block part
layout/base.html

```
 <main class="container my-3">
        {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
    </main>
```

any template file

home.html

```
{% block content %}

... html code 
{% endfor %}
```

so i create one more block for logo

### on base.html we defined the value that was a default one

when base block update from extend template  block value assign  it was render

### base template

```
 {% block main_logo %}
            <a href="/"><img title="Logo" alt=" Logo" src="/static/img/logo.png"></a>
            {% endblock %}
```

### extended template

```
{% block main_logo %}

            <a href="/"><img title="Logo" alt=" Logo" src="/static/img/logo-new-one.png"></a>
{% endblock %}
```